# How to use the array_length() field calculator expression in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

How can I use this field calculator expression in PyQGIS? Right now i have the following code. It generates a new field but it does not fill the field. (see bottom for layer example)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

pv = layer.dataProvider()
pv.addAttributes([QgsField('Count', QVariant.Double)])

layer.updateFields()

expression1 = QgsExpression('array_length(overlay_nearest(PND_Aangrenzend,"",limit:=10,max_distance:=5))')

context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['Count'] = expression1.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If you are ok with creating a new layer: Execute the Field Calculator from processing toolbox, go to History Ctrl+Alt+H, copy the command

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the wider context of your question is, but you can use expressions in QGIS like so:

`layer.selectByExpression(expression)`

This may mean that you can use your expression like so:

```
layerName = "layerNameGoesHere"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
expression = f'array_length(overlay_nearest( @layer ,"",limit:=10,max_distance:=5))'
layer.selectByExpression(expression)
```

Comment: I want to count the adjacent features with pyqgis instead of the field calculator